# Should I compile my VS2008 C++ Win32 applications statically or link them dynamically?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to avoid the dll hell problem and users having to install redistribution packages in case they don't have the dlls.

Is it recommended that I compile my application statically?

Comment: Unless you are planning to give every user a license to Visual Studio, yes.  Just create a decent install program that gets the required DLLs deployed, Windows users expect *that*.

Comment: Are you talking about dynamic vs. static linking to the crt?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If your program is small, and you want someone to be able to simply drop a single executable onto their machine and run it, then static linking is appropriate and is usually the simplest thing to do.

If your program is larger, or if you need an installer anyway (to deploy multiples files, set registry keys, etc.), then you may as well link dynamically, as that can substantially reduce the size of your executable.  You can easily avoid DLL Hell by installating the necessary, redistributable run time DLLs in the same directory as your executable.  If you want to go really pro, you can create an MSI-based installer that includes the merge modules for the run time libraries your project requires.

Do not compile dynamically and expect the user to either already have the DLLs or to install the VCRedist package.  That's difficult to support and it's a pain for your users.

There are [additional considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you're thinking about linking your own DLL to a static run-time library.  If you statically link to the run time, you can end of having multiple instances of the run-time library in a single process.  Any state that the run-time library maintains (like heap information or the position for the next strtok call) will thus be duplicated.  This can lead to subtle bugs unless you're extremely careful.